# Mono: Trouble with reloading assemblies/images and domain

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I have a question that I can't handle for a week, you won't believe it, I've already checked everything that is possible, but it still doesn't want to work correctly. Now I'm writing a script system for my game engine and I need to dynamically recomile/reload .the dll file that contains my library and scripts. To do this, I do:

1. **Initialize Mono.** (I get an appdomain (**MonoDomain***) already created for me)
2. **Open an assembly file.** (dll)
3. **Get an image from this assembly.**
4. **Use mono** (I load internal calls, create C# objects, call functions, etc.).

But at some point I need to recompile/reload this **assembly**, because I change the script code, well, it's understandable. As I understand from a lot of read documentation and various sources, I do not have to describe the **domain**, **assemblies** and **images** while it is active and for this you first need:

1. **Create a new domain.**
2. **Upload the image.**
3. **Connect the image to the object assembly** (thereby making the image status OK)
4. **And only then describe the resources from the last domain.**

But just so that I don't try, either an error occurs in the mono code, or now I have reached the stage that there are no errors, but here is a pointer to a new **image** obtained from a newly loaded assembly (with the same name) is the same and thus it turns out that mono continues to use the same **image** and does not have the updated script values.

This is code of my Mono init:

```cpp
    mono_set_dirs(".", ".");

    // 0. Load first domain, init mono + appdomain + load assembly.
    const char* domainName   = "ForceCS";
    const char* assemblyName = "ForceCS.dll";
    pMonoDomain = mono_jit_init(domainName);
    if (pMonoDomain) {
        pMonoAssembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(pMonoDomain, assemblyName);
        if (pMonoAssembly) {
            pMonoImage = mono_assembly_get_image(pMonoAssembly);
            if (pMonoImage) {
                AddInternalFunctionsAndScriptClasses(); // mono_add_internal_call ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i do some stuff with my dll like create objects or call methods as i said before. And then try to reload the ForceCS.dll.

```cpp
    // 1. Load new domain (Works fine).
    char* newDomainName = "ForceCS";
    MonoDomain* newDomain = mono_domain_create_appdomain(newDomainName, NULL);
    if (!mono_domain_set(newDomain, false)) {
         // Cannot set domain!
    }

    // 2. Load image. (Works fine)
    const char* dllFile = "C:\\Force\\Editor\\ForceCS.dll";
    MonoImageOpenStatus status;
    MonoImage* newImage = mono_image_open(dllFile, &status); ** Problem here: Shows the same address as before and that means that Mono use same .dll.** 

    // 3. Load new assembly. (Works fine).
    MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_assembly_load_from(newImage, mono_image_get_name(newImage), &status);
    if (status != MonoImageOpenStatus::MONO_IMAGE_OK) {
        ///Cannot load assembly!
    }

    assembly = mono_assembly_open(dllFile, &status);

    newImage = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);
    if (newImage) {
        AddInternalFunctionsAndScriptClasses();
    }

    // 4. Inload old domain.
    MonoDomain* domainToUnload = pMonoDomain == nullptr ? mono_domain_get() : pMonoDomain;
    if (domainToUnload && domainToUnload != mono_get_root_domain()) {
        mono_domain_unload(domainToUnload);

        mono_gc_collect(mono_gc_max_generation());
        mono_domain_finalize(domainToUnload, 2000);
        mono_gc_collect(mono_gc_max_generation());

        pMonoDomain = newDomain;
        pMonoImage = newImage;
        pMonoAssembly = assembly;
    }
```

Final problem that image always stays the same, only it works if i load this assembly with different name like ForceCS1.dll, but its not what i want. Please explain me:

1. **When i need to close/free domains, assemblies, images.**
2. **What the connection between assembly-image.**
3. **How reload my .dll assembly.**

I will be grateful for every answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after another week of torment, I finally managed to fix it. In general, as I understood the problem was that I was unloading my only main domain, but I did not create/set to another domain for mono so that he could access it on another thread while the assembly is being reloaded.

In general, I completely rewrote the code, I got something like:

```cpp
int main() {

    // Init Mono Runtime. (Create Root Domain)
    mono_init();
    if (mono_create_domain_and_open_assembly("Scripting Domain", "MyScript.dll"))
        mono_invoke("Script", "OnCreate", 0, NULL, NULL);

    while (true) {
        bool is_reload_request;
        std::cin >> is_reload_request;

        if (is_reload_request) {
            mono_destroy_domain_with_assisisated_assembly(domain);

            // Update new compiled assembly.
            mono_update_assembly("C:\\MonoProject\\MyScript.dll", "C:\\MonoProjectC#\\Binary\\Debug-windows-x86_64\\MyScript.dll");

            if (mono_create_domain_and_open_assembly("Scripting Domain", "MyScript.dll"))
                mono_invoke("Script", "OnCreate", 0, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    mono_jit_cleanup(root_domain);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to explain in detail what I did, for those who may also have encountered such a problem and cannot understand what and how and how to fix it.

### Init Mono & create root domain.

The first thing I did was initialize mono runtime as before, thereby creating a root domain so that in case of a reloading we could switch to it.

```cpp
void mono_init() {
    mono_set_dirs(".", ".");
    root_domain = mono_jit_init_version("Root Domain", "v4.0.30319");
}
```

### Creating Scripting domain, loading assembly.

Then I created a new domain in our case, this is the `Scripting Domain`, and after creating it, I set it for mono (`mono_domain_set(domain, 0)`) so that all subsequent actions are performed from it. And then, just like before, I opened the my assembly `MyScript.dll` through the domain and got pointers to the assembly and the image.

```cpp
bool mono_create_domain_and_open_assembly(char* domain_name, const char* assembly_file) {
    domain = mono_domain_create_appdomain(domain_name, NULL);
    if (domain) {
        mono_domain_set(domain, 0);

        // Open assembly.
        assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(mono_domain_get(), assembly_file);
        if (assembly) {
            image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);
            if (image)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

After this stage, I checked that my assembly was working fine, just created a `Script` object and called the `OnCreate` method from it. I will not write this code so I hope those people who have already worked with mono know how to do it.

### Reloading

Now the reloading itself. In fact, everything is much simpler here than it seems, just before calling `mono_domain_upload`, you need to call `mono_domain_set` to switch our `Scripting Domain` to `Root Domain` for mono when we will creating new domain (new dll).

```cpp
bool mono_destory_domain_with_assisisated_assembly(MonoDomain* domain_to_destroy) {
    if (domain_to_destroy != root_domain) {
        mono_domain_set(root_domain, 0);
        mono_domain_unload(domain_to_destroy);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then compile our C# project and move it to our project (or where you specified the paths for mono). Or how I did it through C++:

```cpp
void mono_update_assembly(char* assembly_path, char* assembly_path_from) {
    if (std::filesystem::exists(assembly_path_from)) {
        
        if (std::filesystem::exists(assembly_path))
            std::filesystem::remove(assembly_path);

        std::filesystem::copy(assembly_path_from, assembly_path);
    }
}
```

And the last step after all that has been done, we just create new domain and load new assembly.